# How to use `assertEqual()` [or equivalent] without much baggage?

Tags: python, assert, python-unittest

I am looking for a method (if available) that can compare two values and raise an assertion error with a meaningful message when the comparison fails.

If I use `assert`, the failure message does not contain what values were compared when then assertion failed.

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> assert a == b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
```

If I use the `assertEqual()` method from the `unittest.TestCase` package, the assertion message contains the values that were compared.

```
        a = 3
        b = 4
>       self.assertEqual(a, b)
E       AssertionError: 3 != 4
```

Note that, here, the assertion error message contains the values that were compared. That is very useful in real-life scenarios and hence necessary for me. The plain `assert` (see above) does not do that.

However, so far, I could use `assertEqual()` only in the class that inherits from `unittest.TestCase` and provides few other required methods like `runTest()`. I want to use `assertEqual()` anywhere, not only in the inherited classes. Is that possible?

I tried the following but they did not work.

```
>>> import unittest
>>> unittest.TestCase.assertEqual(a, b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method failUnlessEqual() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> tc = unittest.TestCase()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 215, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName)
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest.TestCase'>: runTest
>>>
```

Is there any other package or library that offers similar methods like `assertEqual()` that can be easily used without additional constraints?

Comment: Did you tried `unittest.TestCase().assertEqual(a, b)`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM: It does not work either. Same error: `ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest.TestCase'>: runTest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a "helper" new module that provides access to the assert functions. `AssertsAccessor` in this case:

```
from unittest import TestCase

# Dummy TestCase instance, so we can initialize an instance
# and access the assert instance methods
class DummyTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DummyTestCase, self).__init__('_dummy')

    def _dummy(self):
        pass

# A metaclass that makes __getattr__ static
class AssertsAccessorType(type):
    dummy = DummyTestCase()

    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        return getattr(AssertsAccessor.dummy, key)

# The actual accessor, a static class, that redirect the asserts
class AssertsAccessor(object):
    __metaclass__ = AssertsAccessorType
```

The module needs to be created just once, and then all *asserts* from the `unittest` package are accessible, e.g.:

```
AssertsAccessor.assertEquals(1, 2)
```

> AssertionError: 1 != 2

Or another example:

```
AssertsAccessor.assertGreater(1, 2)
```

Which results:

> AssertionError: 1 not greater than 2

Assuming the module created for the accessor is named `assertions`, the common usage in the code would look like:

```
from assertions import AssertsAccessor

def foo(small_arg, big_arg):
    AssertsAccessor.assertGreater(big_arg, small_arg)
    # some logic here
```

Comment: If you replace `from assertions import AssertsAccessor` by `from sklearn.utils._testing import _dummy as AssertsAccessor` you can skip every previous steps, including creating file `assertions.py` (I myself use a keyword shorter than AssertsAccessor).

Answer (score 5):

You have to give the assertion message by hand:

```
assert a == b, '%s != %s' % (a, b)
# AssertionError: 3 != 4
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. However, it is a lot of extra typing :) In fact, typing extra without adding extra "information" to the source code. If nothing comes out, then I am considering to create my own tiny library to do such wrapping :).

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at numpy.testing?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.testing.html

Amongst others it has:
assert_almost_equal(actual, desired[, ...]) Raises an AssertionError if two items are not equal up to desired precision.

This assert prints out actual and desired.  If you ramp up precision the comparison is arbitrarily close to == (For floats)

Comment: Interesting. I haven't checked `numpy.testing` earlier. They do have `assert_equal()` too! However, they do not have the assertXxx() that are offered by `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar in the past and end-up writing short custom assert which accept any condition as input.

```
import inspect

def custom_assert(condition):
    if not condition:
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        frame = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1]
        call_signature = inspect.getframeinfo(frame[0]).code_context[0].strip()

        import re
        argument = re.search('\((.+)\)', call_signature).group(1)
        if '!=' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('!=','==')
        elif '==' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('==','!=')
        elif '<' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('<','>=')
        elif '>' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('>','<=')
        elif '>=' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('>=','<')
        elif '<=' in argument:
            argument = argument.replace('<=','>')

        raise AssertionError(argument)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    custom_assert(2 == 1)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom_assert.py", line 27, in <module>
    custom_assert(2 == 1)
  File "custom_assert.py", line 24, in custom_assert
    raise AssertionError(argument)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea too. Thank you. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The assertEqual or any other assertXxx() method expects the first argument to be an object reference. Generally we call the method as `self.assertEqual(first, second, msg=None)`.
Here `self` satisfies the first expected argument. To circumvent this situation we can do the following:

```
from unittest import TestCase as tc
def some_func():
    dummy_obj = tc()
    tc.assertEqual(dummy_obj, 123, 123, msg='Not Equal')
```

The reason for this behavior is Hangover from XUnit frameworks.

Comment: You can replace last two lines by `tc().assertEqual(123, 123, msg='Not Equal')`